# Is there an ArcGIS 10 Amazon Machine Image (AMI) patched with SP4?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, amazon-ec2

I know you can patch the SP3 AMI with SP4, but is there a SP4 AMI for ArcGIS server 10 and if it exists, what is the AMI Name (or AMI ID).

I know Esri has to specifically share an AMI with my Amazon account before it is discoverable in an AMI search.  But you wouldn't know to ask for it.

Comment: "New ArcGIS Server on Amazon EC2 AMIs (Amazon Machine Images) that include 10.0 SP4 are available to existing ArcGIS Server on Amazon EC2 customers"  http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=66&MetaID=1843